# Move .app with .command on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, command

I'm trying to make a command to move an app I made to the applications directory without having to make a full installer. Right now this is the command I'm running with the proper permissions (I used chmod +x install.command):

```
mv My\ Application.app /Applications/
```

This gives me the output

```
mv: My Application.app: No such file or directory
logout
```

If I just run this command in the terminal it works, any idea what's going on?

**EDIT:**

I can't seem to manipulate "My Application.app" at all from the .command file. I tried running just `rm -r "My Application.app"` and it still can't seem to find the directory. The .command is in the same directory as "My Application.app"

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't running this script from the dir that holds "My Application.app"
then you need to have the full path to "My Application.app".

Also you should try it with quotes.

```
mv "/path/to/My Application.app" /Applications/
```

Comment: I'm running the .command from the same directory as "My Application.app"

Comment: @beenjaminnn weird.... did you spell Application correctly in your .command, remember capital letters are important in the spelling.

Answer (score 0):

`.command` files don't run with their current working directory set to the directory they are in, which is why it doesn't work; it's running in your home directory. You'll need to use either an absolute path, or a path relative to your home directory, not relative to the directory of the `.command` file.